# How to get SQL Function run a different query and return value from either query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, option-type

I need a function, but cannot seem to get it quite right, I have looked at examples here and elsewhere and cannot seem to get this just right, I need an optional item to be included in my query, I have this query (which works):

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
(1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
WHERE Title = @Title AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer
ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
```

This works within a Function, however the Manufacturer is Optional for this search - which is to find the description of a similar item, if none is present, the other query is:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
(1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
WHERE Title = @Title ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
```

Which is missing the Manufacturer, how to I get my function to use either query based on the Manufacturer Value being present or not.
The reason is I will have a function which first checks an SKU for a Description, if it is not present - it uses this method to get a Description from a Similar Product, then updates the product being added with the similar product's description.

Here is the function so far:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDescriptionByTitleManufacturer]
(   
    @Title varchar(400),
    @Manufacturer varchar(160)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
    (1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
    WHERE Title = @Title AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer
    ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
    )
```

I've tried adding BEGINs and IF...ELSEs but get errors or syntax problems each way I try it, I want to be able to do something like this pseudo-function (which does not work):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDescriptionByTitleManufacturer]
(   
    @Title varchar(400),
    @Manufacturer varchar(160)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
IF (@Manufacturer = Null)
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
    (1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
    WHERE Title = @Title ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
    )
ELSE
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
    (1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
    WHERE Title = @Title AND Manufacturer = @Manufacturer
    ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
    )
```

END

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDescriptionByTitleManufacturer]
(   
    @Title varchar(400),
    @Manufacturer varchar(160)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
    (1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
    WHERE Title = @Title AND (@Manufacturer IS NULL OR Manufacturer = @Manufacturer)
    ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
    )
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed being able to do it this way! Got sidelined by trying to do it as an IF...ELSE clause. I do want to be able to chain functions together based on their return value so would be handy if you can do optional returns on a function - but this answers my question directly for now.

Comment: `(@Manufacturer IS NULL OR Manufacturer = @Manufacturer)` will not use an index.  However if the OP is on a certain version of SQL Server 2008, there is a way to make this use an index, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the recompile method - will try this, marked as answer, left it open to see if there were any function condition answers, but this solution is fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `AND (Manufacturer = @Manufacturer OR @Manufacturer IS NULL)` you eliminate the use of an index.  There are many subtle performance implications to dynamic searchs, you should read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

If you have the proper SQL Server 2008 version (SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later), you can use this little trick to actually use an index:

add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` onto your query,  [see Erland's article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#static), and SQL Server will resolve the `OR` from within `(@Manufacturer IS NULL OR Manufacturer = @Manufacturer)` before the query plan is created based on the values of the local variables, and an index can be used.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDescriptionByTitleManufacturer]
(   
    @Title varchar(400),
    @Manufacturer varchar(160)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(SELECT TOP 100 
     PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000),Description)) AS LenDesc 
     FROM tblItem
         WHERE Title = @Title 
         AND (@Manufacturer IS NULL OR Manufacturer = @Manufacturer)
     ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
     OPTION (RECOMPILE) ---<<<<only valid for SQL 2008 SP1 CU5 (10.0.2746) and later
)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using NULL when manufacturer doesnt apply:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT SKU, Description, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR
(1000),Description)) AS LenDesc FROM tblItem
WHERE Title = @Title AND (Manufacturer = @Manufacturer OR @Manufacturer IS NULL)
ORDER BY LenDesc DESC
```